# Machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning

Can someone help me with the below requirement which is:

I want to build a model that should understand a piece of code and predict the programming language based on the code contents.

Any lead would be highly appreciated.

eg:

```
private int input = 0;
 
public int getter() {
   return input;
}
public void setter(int in) {
  input = in;
}
```

**Output - Java**

Thanks

Comment: Would just feeding the code to a bunch of compilers and see who compiles be a valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use some pretrained language model to run on the test data. Test data can be some statements and the language they belong to and you can proceed as a classification task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use N-grams to understand which keyword belongs to which language. You can check it out: [ngram resource](https://medium.com/machine-learning-at-petiteprogrammer/detecting-the-programming-language-of-source-code-snippets-using-machine-learning-and-neural-e275ca4ce93e)

You can find source codes by web scraping through GitHub. So, you can create a source code and programming language dataset by yourself. If you want to go deeper, there are books about this topic. [programming language detection book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-08979-9_39)